# Where to put validator for Django model field?

Tags: django, django-models

The Django documentation shows an [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/validators/) of a custom validator for a model field.  However the doc doesn't say where to put the validator function in your code.  If I put it in my models.py file in either location (as shown below), I get this error when I try to start the server:

```
NameError: name 'validate_name' is not defined
```

Where is the right location for this validate_name function?  Thanks.

```
# models.py, example 1
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class CommentModel(models.Model):
    # I get the error if I define the validator here
    def validate_name(value):
        if value == '':
            raise ValidationError(u'%s cannot be left blank' % value)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, validators=[validate_name])


# models.py, example 2
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

# I also get the error if I define the validator here
def validate_name(value):
    if value == '':
        raise ValidationError(u'%s cannot be left blank' % value)

class CommentModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, validators=[validate_name])
```

Comment: the second case is correct and that is the way to go.And show us the stacktrace or error message and paste it here.

Comment: try `self.validate_name` in the first case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

declaring your validation method within your models file but outside your class declaration (example 2) should work fine

you may be getting a NameError if you're using the function within another file without importing the method first